# How to swap the values of 2 columns in a row ? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called `Info` with `ID, tName, restName` and `isOpen` columns.

And I have values like this for example:

```
ID (Unique) | tName |  restName | isOpen
-----------------------------------------    
 9          - TN10  -    RN10   -   0
10          - TN10  -    RN10   -   1
11          - TN11  -    RN11   -   1
```

I want to swap `tName` and `restName` values where `isOpen=1`.

```
ID (Unique) | tName |  restName | isOpen
----------------------------------------    
 9          - TN10  -    RN10   -   0
10          - TN11  -    RN11   -   1
11          - TN10  -    RN10   -   1
```

I know the values that I should change before query, I mean I know what `tName-restName` should change to what `tName-restName`.

I am very new to queries and I just can't figure out how to swap values. If it was a language like C, I would just use a temp value and swap them. Can it be done with 1 query? I saw that it is easy when swapping columns but I couldn't find any useful material for my situation.

## UPDATE

I forgot to tell that I don't know about the values of IDs at the time and don't want to get them with another query.

I want to make a query like "swap values where `restName=RN10` and `tName=TN10` with `restName=RN11` and `tName=TN11` and `isOpen=1`" if it is possible. So the selection is about `tName`, `restName` and `isOpen` i guess.

Thank you for your replies,

Have a nice day

Comment: Are you just trying to do this for the two rows shown in the question with ids 10 and 11 or a greater number? If a greater number what is the logic for selection of a pair of rows?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a query after long tries :) that does what i want completely but I can't be sure if it is completely true or not. I would be happy if someone can check it and tell. Thank you...

```
UPDATE Info 
SET tName = CASE tName 
WHEN @tNameOld THEN @tNameNew
WHEN @tNameNew THEN @tNameOld
END,     
restName = CASE restName 
WHEN @restNameOld THEN @restNameNew
WHEN @restNameNew THEN @restNameOld 
END     
WHERE tName in (@tNameOld,@tNameNew)     
AND isOpen=1     
AND restName in (@restNameOld,@restNameNew)
```

Comment: This will perform a swap on a row where, say, it matches the old values, without necessarily confirming that there's also going to be a row with the new values that also has `isOpen` equal to 1. It may also create false matches where, say, a row has the old `tName` and the new `restNew` value. Both of these may be of no concern in your data, but are circumstances I was careful to avoid with my solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I ask one more question? 
What if there is only one `isOpen=1` statement for the same tName and restName? Then it is ok to use this right ?

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic swap, let's say we have this:

```
declare @Swaps table (
    tFirst varchar(10) not null,
    rFirst varchar(10) not null,
    tSecond varchar(10) not null,
    rSecond varchar(10) not null
)
INSERT INTO @Swaps (tFirst,rFirst,tSecond,rSecond) VALUES
                   ('TN10','RN10','TN11','RN11')
                 --And more rows
UPDATE i
SET tName = o.tName,
    restName = o.restName
FROM @Swaps s
    inner join
     Info i
        on
           ((s.tFirst = i.tName and s.rFirst = i.restName) or
            (s.tSecond = i.tName and s.rSecond = i.restName)) and
           i.IsOpen = 1
    inner join
     Info o
        on
           ((s.tFirst = o.tName and s.rFirst = o.restName) or
            (s.tSecond = o.tName and s.rSecond = o.restName)) and
           o.IsOpen = 1 and
           (i.tName <> o.tName or i.restName <> o.restName)
```

---

(*Earlier answer*)

For this specific swap, it can be done as:

```
UPDATE i
SET tName = o.tName
    restName = o.restName
FROM Info i
INNER JOIN Info o
on (
  (i.ID = 10 and o.ID = 11) or
  (i.ID = 11 and o.ID = 10)
)
```

But I'm not sure how large your actual problem size is. If there are lots of swaps, you might want to store all of those combination in another (temp) table and do a further join to that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to be more clear. About your answer I don't have the ID's specifically and I need to check for isOpen too, just tried to give an example about what I am going to do with the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #Info
(
    ID INT Primary Key NOT NULL,
    tName Varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    restName VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
    isOpen bit NOT NULL

)

INSERT INTO #Info   VALUES 
          ( 9, 'TN10', 'RN10', 0),
    (10, 'TN10','RN10', 1),
    (11, 'TN11','RN11', 1)

select *
from #Info


UPDATE #info
    SET tName = newTName,
        restName = newRestName
FROM #info i
INNER JOIN 
    (
        select id, tName newRestName, restName newTName  
        from #Info
        WHERE isOpen = 1
    ) i2
ON i.ID = i2.ID

SELECT *
FROM #Info
```